# jQuery Change class of specific li elements basis JSON array input

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm building a dynamic table with the months shown in one row. Each 'td' in the row will have a 12-month 'li' ccs grid, where I'm trying to apply a different class to certain months. The months to be highlighted differently, come from the JSON array used to populate the grid.

However, the jquery is not working and the console error I'm getting is 'li is not defined'.

I'm initially creating a 12-month 'li' grid with a certain class as follows:

```
var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    var MonthList = jQuery('ul.wrapper')
    jQuery.each(MonthArr, function(i){
      var li = jQuery('<li>').addClass('boxFalse').addClass('cross').appendTo(MonthList);      
    })
```

On that, I'me trying to change the change the class of the specific months mentioned in the array:

```
if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Best months to visit') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {
        var SelectedMonthArr = jQuery(this).text().split(',');
        for (i=0; i<SelectedMonthArr.length; i++){
          var SelectedMonthArrEach = SelectedMonthArr[i];
        }
        jQuery(MonthList > li).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == SelectedMonthArrEach.text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }  
        });
        console.log(MonthList);
        jQuery(this).empty().append(MonthList);
    });
```

The consolidated jquery for this specific exercise is as follows:

```
jQuery('.divResult table tbody tr td').each(function ($) {
    var MonthArr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    var MonthList = jQuery('ul.wrapper')
    jQuery.each(MonthArr, function(i){
      var li = jQuery('<li>').addClass('boxFalse').addClass('cross').appendTo(MonthList);      
    })

      if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Best months to visit') jQuery(this).nextAll("td").each(function ($) {
        var SelectedMonthArr = jQuery(this).text().split(',');
        for (i=0; i<SelectedMonthArr.length; i++){
          var SelectedMonthArrEach = SelectedMonthArr[i];
        }
        jQuery(MonthList > li).each (function(){
          if (jQuery(this).text() == SelectedMonthArrEach.text()) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('boxTrue').addClass('tick');
          }  
        });
        console.log(MonthList);
        jQuery(this).empty().append(MonthList);
    });
  });
```

I needed the class of the specific 'li' to change but it isn't happening.

Plese help me with where am I going wrong. 
The JSFiddle for the whole code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/91egL48c/1/

Comment: So many things going on. Here is an updated version, please tell me what steps to take and what expected output is https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Lc8u40gf/12/ - also where is 'Best months to visit' ?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan ! I've reworked the code and corrected some mistakes in it. I'm now getting the 'li' grid in the 'td' as required. But the class change for select 'li' isn't happening. :/ Find updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/hv8w6fbq/1/ . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the code you have

```
 jQuery(MonthList > li).each (function(){
```

`li` will be a variable and `>` a operator, you need

```
 MonthList.find('> li').each(function() {
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5howryng/)

Comment: `$("li",MonthList).each`

Comment: OR 
`var $MonthList = $('ul.wrapper li')`

Comment: Thanks @madalinivascu for the quick reply!! While this got rid of the console error, the 12-month 'li' grid is still not being generated in the Key Months row 'td' . :/  I think I have nested the functions incorrectly, but unable to figure where I have gone wrong. :( :(

Comment: Also thanks to @mplungjan! Would appreciate if you could have a look at the rest of the code as the 12-month 'li' grid is still not being generated as required.

Comment: you are not appending `MonthList` to the page, you need to do that